# See the results of phase 1 computation in phase 0

Tags: racket, metaprogramming

Suppose I have some module with non-trivial `define` "override" in Racket. That "override" collects information about the procedure-body and stores it into a map (during the **compilation** phase). Now I need to use the collected information during the **runtime** phase. The straightforward aproach doesn`t seem to work:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax racket))

(define-for-syntax map-that-should-be-used-in-phase-0 (make-hash))
(define-for-syntax (fill-in-useful-information n) (hash-set! map-that-should-be-used-in-phase-0 n n))

; Suppose that some useful information is collected here and stored into a map
(define-syntax (fill-in-map stx)
  (begin
    (fill-in-useful-information 1)
    (fill-in-useful-information 2)
    (syntax/loc stx (displayln "OK, the map is filled, but I cannot see it here"))))

(define-syntax (print-that-map stx)
  (syntax/loc stx (displayln map-that-should-be-used-in-phase-0))) ; <-- This can not be compiled

(fill-in-map)
(print-that-map)
```

Can I do it in Racket? If yes then how? Any hints will be greately appreciated!

Comment: I admit, I am at a complete loss as to why this question was downvoted. Seems like a fine question to me.

Comment: @AlexisKing Thanks for the remark, I also wonder why. I expected them to  explain the reason in commets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An identifier referencing a variable cannot be compiled, but the value it refers to can, as long as it's one of the built-in data structures provided by Racket, and as long as it's immutable.

You can stick a hash table value into a syntax object using `quasisyntax` and `unsyntax`.

```
> (quasisyntax (foo #,(hash 'a 4 'b 16)))
#<syntax:5:15 (foo #hash((a . 4) (b . 16)))>
```

You can do the same thing to communicate one-way from compile-time to run-time.

```
(define-for-syntax (hash->immutable-hash hsh)
  (make-immutable-hash (hash->list hsh)))

(define-syntax (print-that-map stx)
  (quasisyntax/loc stx (displayln #,(hash->immutable-hash map-that-should-be-used-in-phase-0))))
```